# If $x\in R$ and the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are complex, then the sign of $a^2x^2+abx+ac$ is

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

A) Always positive

B) Always negative

C)Always non-negative

D) Always zero

Obviously, this isn’t a solving question, so I can’t really show any working here (I would have otherwise). I didn’t really understand the question, so help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ also real?

Comment: @Arthur I would assume them to be, although it’s not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is always positive which is $(A)$

Note that $$a^2x^2+abx+ac=0 $$ is a parabola open upward and it has the same complex roots as the original equatin therefore it must be always positive.

Comment: How is it a parabola open upwards? Depending upon the sign of $a$, it could also open downward, provided if does not touch the x axis

Comment: You have $a^2$ as the coefficient of $x^2$ which is always positive so it is open upwards.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$
a^2x^2+abx+ac = a\left(ax^2+bx+c\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

If the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are complex, the trinomial $ax^2+bx+c$ keeps a constant, non-zero sign in the reals, and so does $a^2x^2+abx+ac$. And for large enough $x$, this is perforce be positive.

Comment: So $a$ HAS to be positive?

Comment: @Aditya: what makes you think that ?